# How to get archived events based on end date for a content type with a start date and end date field?

Tags: views

Create a content type Event with fields for Start date and End date. Validate the creation of events where Start date cannot be in the past and End date cannot be less than start date. Create a View where the Start date & End date are exposed filters and end date validated as in content creation page. The View should also filter expired events (i.e. Content with expired End date) and displayed in a similar view display named Archived Events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Archived events get based on an end date.

Go to view named `archived events`. Then click the end date exposed filter in FILTER CRITERIA. Check Filter type to expose is `single filter`. Then below operator drop down box choice `is less than`. Next drop down box choice `enter relative date`. Below now shows Relative date text box give `now`.
Then click on Apply button.